# WARN SparkContext: Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing this as I cannot find the answer to this problem. I am using PySpark and running a script, except I cannot see where my other Spark sessions are or close them down. What is the best way to do the following?

I am not initializing any other `SparkContext` within this `spark-submit` job so it must be contexts left behind from some previous run? Note that i do not want to `allowmultiplecontexts`.

1. Check running `SparkContexts`.
2. Use existing `SparkContexts` if they exist.
3. Best way to modify this code.

```
from src import config
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from visualize_main import app
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

spark =SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName("morphy_test111_dgdfgdf").config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

I submit the job with teh following

```
spark-submit /app.py
```

I get this error

```
WARN SparkContext: Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
```

Any help much appreciated as I have not found a proper explanation for this.

Comment: Why do you need to allow multiple contexts ?

Comment: I do not. But every time i run spark submit again i get the error above and not sure how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

> a) Check running sparkcontexts b) Use existing sparkcontexts if they exist c) best way to modify this code

In that case remove:

```
SparkContext.stop("morphy_test11")
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
```

and leave only

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName("morphy_test111_dgdfgdf").config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

If there is an active context it will be reused.

Comment: Thank you. However, Using only the SparkSession.builder line did not work for me  and hence why i tried adding the other three lines and that doesn't work either